# AFNetworking 2 не могу прикрутить куки к запросу

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

В общем нужно передать куки с запросов, ниже 2 версии ещё как-то опнятно было, сейчас же запрос:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ссылка"] parameters:"параметры" success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

как к этому коду передать куки? Помогите пожалуйста, уже не знаю что его делать, никак не могу инфу найти(

Comment: Когда Вы поймете, что есть куки, тогда вы будете искать в документации по установке Хедеров в запросы: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#class_methods 
в особенности метод: setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишите где-то после первого запроса к серверу (авторизации - когда куки передавать не нужно):

```
NSData *cookieData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cookieData forKey:@"ApplicationCookie"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Затем при старте приложения каждый раз вытягиваете куки из NSUserDefaults, если они там есть то:

```
NSData *cookieData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ApplicationCookie"];
        if ([cookieData length] > 0) {
            NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:cookieData];
            for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
                [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Все хорошо, только @VladimirBabochin юзает AFNetworking.

Comment: @bimawa, Я прочитал, а в чём проблема?

Comment: @Ковальский а не в чем, я не внимательно Ваш код прочитал ^_^

Comment: @Ковальский, спасибо, все заработало :)

Comment: хранить cookie в NSUserDefaults - плохая примета. Минимум в NSKeychain